Failure on DX11Texturesavetofile for B5G6R5_UNORM format
I have a protocol to prepare with a combining shader a texture from two other textures and saving it in RGBA8_UNORM DDS format using DX11SaveTextureToFile. Works fine. It appears to me that I don't really need the A channel and want to use RGB565_UNORM instead with the corresponding combining shader. But the outputed file can't be reopen, including with DXtexTool. The DX11CfreateShaderResourceViewFromFile return E_FAIL.
I've seen that some header is added for non standard RGB format but I guess this may be handled by the loader/saver functions.
I use DX11CfreateShaderResourceViewFromFile this way:
DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(pDC11, FileName, NULL, NULL, &pSRV, NULL);

Should I add someting to consider any added header?
Answering the comment the code used for this combination
ID3D11Texture2D* pTex = NULL;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* pRTVGen = NULL;
DXGI_FORMAT RTVFormat = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;//changing to B5G6R5 is my problem
pTex = CreateTexture2D(256, 256, RTVFormat, /D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET);//function to create the texture that works in all my projects
pRTVGen = CreateRenderTargetView2D(pTex, RTVFormat); );//function to create the rendertarget that works in all my projects
gpCurShader = SetShader2(dwSD_GenerateMaps);
gpDC11->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &gpSampler[cS_Linear]);
gpDC11->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &pRTVGen, NULL);
D3D11_VIEWPORT VP;
VP.Height = 256;
VP.Width = 256;
VP.TopLeftX = VP.TopLeftY = 0;
VP.MinDepth = 0;
VP.MaxDepth = 1;
gpDC11->RSSetViewports(1, &VP);
for (DWORD n = 0; n < 30; n++)
{
    if (n < 10)sprintf_s(buf, "C:\\Wired\\Images\\Ripples\\ripples_000%d.bmp", n);
    else sprintf_s(buf, "C:\\Wired\\Images\\Ripples\\ripples_00%d.bmp", n);
    DWORD RippleIndex = AddSRVMaterial(buf, NULL, 0);

//AddSRVMaterial add the new created texture to a gppS texture list
//AddSRVMaterial    contains HRESULT hr = D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFileA(gpD11, File, NULL, NULL, &pSRV, NULL); pSRV is the ShaderResource created
    gpDC11->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &gppS[RippleIndex]->pSRV);
    if (n < 10)sprintf_s(buf, "C:\\Wired\\Images\\Ripples\\NNoise000%d.bmp", n);
    else sprintf_s(buf, "C:\\Wired\\Images\\Ripples\\NNoise00%d.bmp", n);
    DWORD NoiseIndex = AddSRVMaterial(buf, NULL, 0);//function to add the new textue to my texture list
    gpDC11->PSSetShaderResources(1, 1, &gppS[NoiseIndex]->pSRV);//gppS is my texture list
    RenderMeshSingle(gpMeshSceneQuad);//function to render to the texture
    WCHAR wbuf[MAX_PATH];
    if (n < 10)wsprintf(wbuf, L"C:\\Wired\\Images\\Ripples\\ripplesnoise_000%d.dds", n);
    else wsprintf(wbuf, L"C:\\Wired\\Images\\Ripples\\ripplesnoise_00%d.dds", n);
    HRESULT hr = D3DX11SaveTextureToFile(gpDC11, pTex, D3DX11_IFF_DDS, wbuf);
    if (hr != S_OK)//Note hr is always S_OK even when the output file is uncorrect for DX11CreateFromFile//
    {
        sprintf_s(buf, "Error DXSaveTex %d\n", hr);
        OutputDebugStringA(buf);
    }
    pRTVGen->Release();
    pTex->Release();

content of
ID3D11Texture2D* CreateTexture2D(DWORD Width, DWORD Height,         DXGI_FORMAT Format, UINT BindFlag)
{
ID3D11Texture2D* pTex = NULL;
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC TexDesc;
ZeroMemory(&TexDesc, sizeof(TexDesc));
TexDesc.Width = Width;
TexDesc.Height = Height;
TexDesc.MipLevels = 1;
TexDesc.ArraySize = 1;
TexDesc.Format = Format;
TexDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
TexDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
TexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
TexDesc.BindFlags = BindFlag;
TexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
TexDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
HRESULT hr = gpD11->CreateTexture2D(&TexDesc, NULL, &pTex);
if (FAILED(hr)) return NULL;
return pTex;
}

Content of
ID3D11RenderTargetView* CreateRenderTargetView2D(ID3D11Texture2D* pText2D, DXGI_FORMAT Format)
{
ID3D11RenderTargetView* pRTV = NULL;
D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC RTVDesc;
RTVDesc.Format = Format;
RTVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
RTVDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
HRESULT hr = gpD11->CreateRenderTargetView(pText2D, &RTVDesc, &pRTV);
if (FAILED(hr)) return NULL;
return pRTV;
}

pixel shader to fill the texture.
An ifdef is used to select RGBA8 or BGR565 formats during compilation
#ifdef SM_GENF3
float3 PS_GenRain(PS_INPUTQUAD Input): SV_TARGET
{
float3 FinalColor = float3(0,0,0);
FinalColor.rg = txRipple.Sample(samLinear, Input.Tex).rg;
FinalColor.b = txNoise.Sample(samLinear, Input.Tex).b;
return FinalColor;
};
#else
float4 PS_GenRain(PS_INPUTQUAD Input): SV_TARGET
{
float4 FinalColor = float4(0,0,0,0);
FinalColor.rg = txRipple.Sample(samLinear, Input.Tex).rg;
FinalColor.ba = txNoise.Sample(samLinear, Input.Tex).rb;
return FinalColor;
};
#endif

Result for n =0 with RGBA8


Can you show how you're making this file in the first place?

D3DX11 is legacy and has numerous limitations and bugs. For details on it's status, see Living Without D3DX and Legacy D3DX on NuGet.
D3DX11 was never updated to support 16bpp formats because they were explictily removed for DirectX 10 and not added back until Windows 8 DirectX 11.1.
A better solution would be to use DirectXTex or DirectX Tool Kit for DX11.
Also keep in mind the legacy DXTex tool was never updated past Direct3D 9, and uses D3DX9 which has a very old copy of the various codecs in it.

thanks I've started looking for directxtex.

My environnement is too old (VS 2013). I can't use easily DirectXTex in my code at the moment.
